# commumicating between windows app and android app

Tags: android, windows, socket.io

I'm sorry if this is a very general question but I don't know where to start so I'm looking for ideas.

I have a windows app (music score editing) and I'm currently porting it to Andriod which is coming along well.

I would like to add the feature than documents created in the windows app can be sent to the users android tablet. I was wondering, how would I write some kind of listener on Android that the windows side could open a socket or something to and send data across to it, assuming both are on the same local network.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think sending files directly over a local network isn't the best approach. You are prone to many user complaints that the sharing isn't working.. and this will mostly be due to their own network configuration issues.

Why not use a service like DropBox to implement file sharing?

Services like DropBox offer simple API that can be used in apps in order to save files into a remote folder, and read files from a remote folder.

This way, users will not have to be in the same network at all.. and most of the heavy-lifting of implementing file sharing will be done by a service that is focused around that.

**Addition:**

If you don't want to require an account for a separate service like DropBox, consider this approach: Implement a very simple DropBox-like service on your own web server. Make a simple script that will allow users to upload a file to your server anonymously via HTTP. After upload, they will receive a 5 digit id for this file, or some other link they could share. When using this id or link from the 2nd app, the file could be downloaded (again via HTTP). If you delete files automatically from the server after a few hours, you will not run out of space.

You can implement such a service with about 20 lines of PHP code. And the required apps code is extremely simple (since it only relies on HTTP). If you're worried about the costs of a web server, you can get one from about $5/month or even use a free service like Google App Engine (free if your bandwidth+space requirements are low).

Code [example](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) for the file upload. Downloading should be simple enough to do alone. Regarding the periodical file delete - the obvious approach is [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) but I think it's easy to manage without it. Whenever you accept a new upload (in the PHP script), go over all the downloads and delete old ones.

Comment: interesting idea but that requires the use to get a dropbox account right? also, is it supported on the windows side? looks like its just android and ios APIs. i'll look into it however. thanks

Comment: I'll be happy to receive a comment about the downvote so I could improve the answer

Comment: thanks, i do want to support users uploading to to my website anyhow. so i'll look into that. you don't happen to have any sample code to do that do you? BTW, i don't know where that down vote came from, certainly not me.

Comment: here's an example: http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/ The PHP script takes 9 lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a small thing so my windows app can find an instance of my android app running on the local network, here it is. this is the android code first

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class TabSyncServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ServerSocket mServerSocket = null;
    Socket mSocket = null;
    DataInputStream mDataInputStream = null;
    DataOutputStream mDataOutputStream = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        try {
            mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(2112);
            //System.out.println("Listening :2112");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        byte[] bytebuf = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            try {

                mSocket = mServerSocket.accept();
                mDataInputStream = new DataInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
                mDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
                Log.d("TabSyncServer", "ip: " + mSocket.getInetAddress());
                mDataInputStream.read(bytebuf);

                String str = new String(bytebuf, "UTF8");
                Log.d("TabSyncServer", "message: " + str);
                if(str.contains("Hello Android")) {
                    Log.d("TabSyncServer", "sending reply");
                    mDataOutputStream.writeBytes("Hello Windows");
                }

                // 

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (mSocket != null) {
                    try {
                        mSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (mDataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        mDataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (mDataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        mDataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and the windows MFC code

```
    void CMainFrame::OnBrowseMobile() {


    CMobileSync* con = new CMobileSync();
    CString ipaddr_base;
    int my_last_digit;
    if(!con->getMyIP(ipaddr_base, my_last_digit)) {
        setMobilePath("Can't find local network");
        return;
    }


    for(int i=1 ; i<98 ; i++) {
        if(i==my_last_digit)
            continue;       // don;t check self

        CString ipaddr; ipaddr.Format("%s.%d", ipaddr_base, i);
        bool res = con->ConnectToHost(ipaddr);
        if(res) {
            res = con->SendMsg ("Hello Android");

            if(res) {
                TRACE1("send ok %s\n",ipaddr.GetBuffer());
#define RD_BUF_LEN 80
                char buffer[RD_BUF_LEN];
                if(con->ListenOnPortBlocking(buffer, RD_BUF_LEN)) {
                    if(strncmp(buffer, "Hello Windows", 12)==0) {
                        TRACE1("reply ok %s", buffer);
                        setMobilePath(ipaddr);
                        con->CloseConnection ();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                TRACE("send FAILED\n");
            }
        }
        con->CloseConnection ();
    }
    setMobilePath("No TabTrax on local network");
}

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock.h>
#include "MobileSync.h"

#define TTPORT 2112
bool CMobileSync::getMyIP(CString& ipaddr_front, int& ipaddr_lastdigit)
{
    char szBuffer[1024];

    #ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 0);
    if(::WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0)
        return false;
    #endif


    if(gethostname(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      #ifdef WIN32
      WSACleanup();
      #endif
      return false;
    }

    struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(szBuffer);
    if(host == NULL)
    {
      #ifdef WIN32
      WSACleanup();
      #endif
      return false;
    }

    //Obtain the computer's IP
    unsigned char b1, b2, b3, b4;
    b1 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b1;
    b2 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b2;
    b3 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b3;
    b4 = ((struct in_addr *)(host->h_addr))->S_un.S_un_b.s_b4;

    ipaddr_front.Format("%d.%d.%d", b1, b2, b3);
    ipaddr_lastdigit = b4;
    #ifdef WIN32
    WSACleanup();
    #endif
    return true;
}

//CONNECTTOHOST – Connects to a remote host
bool CMobileSync::ConnectToHost(const char* IPAddress)
{
    //Start up Winsock…
    WSADATA wsadata;

    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);

    //Did something happen?
    if (error)
        return false;

    //Did we get the right Winsock version?
    if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
        return false;
    }

    //Fill out the information needed to initialize a socket…
    SOCKADDR_IN target; //Socket address information

    target.sin_family = AF_INET; // address family Internet
    target.sin_port = htons (TTPORT); //Port to connect on
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (IPAddress); //Target IP

    mSocket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket
    if (mSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't create the socket
    }  

    //Try connecting...

    if (connect(mSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't connect
    }

    return true; //Success
}

//CLOSECONNECTION – shuts down the socket and closes any connection on it
void CMobileSync::CloseConnection ()
{
    //Close the socket if it exists
    if (mSocket)
        closesocket(mSocket);
    mSocket=0;

    WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
}

int CMobileSync::SendMsg (char* szpText, int buflen)
{
    if(buflen==0)
        buflen = strlen(szpText);
    int ret = send(mSocket, szpText, buflen, 0);
    TRACE1("CMobileSync::SendMsg sent %d bytes\n", ret);
    return ret;
}

WSADATA w;

//LISTENONPORT – Listens on a specified port for incoming connections 
//or data
bool CMobileSync::ListenOnPortBlocking(char* buffer, int buflen)
{
    //Now we can start listening (allowing as many connections as possible to  
    //be made at the same time using SOMAXCONN). You could specify any 
    //integer value equal to or lesser than SOMAXCONN instead for custom 
    //purposes). The function will not //return until a connection request is 
    //made
    // listen(s, SOMAXCONN);

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); //Clear the buffer

    int iTimeout = 1600;
    setsockopt( mSocket,  SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&iTimeout, sizeof(iTimeout));

    //Put the incoming text into our buffer
    int ret = recv (mSocket, buffer, buflen-1, 0); 

    //Don't forget to clean up with CloseConnection()!

    if(ret != SOCKET_ERROR)
        return true;

    int err = WSAGetLastError();
    return false;
}
```

its not tested extensively but it is running

this maybe useful to someone